# JavaScript: Move <div> element to the right after 2 items in a column

Tags: javascript, css, html, web

I don't really know how to explain this in words, so I'll do in a photo:

[image: explaination]
So, basically I want the code to write the div tag to the right after 2 items on the same columns. The arrows will show the pattern of the items.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    imgs = ["/images/toilet.jpg", "/images/kitchen.jpg"]; 
    for (var i=0,l=imgs.length; i<l; i++)
    {
        document.write("<div class='item'><img class='imgitem' src='" + imgs[i] + "'></div>");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just want to affect layout? That is probably easiest through CSS.

Comment: Please don't use document.write either! Use appendChild etc. to add the elements to a parent element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm...going down your current course of action (using JavaScript) to achieve this behaviour, you could use something like this (changed document.write to an innerHTML approach, I hope you don't mind):

```
imgs = ["/images/toilet.jpg", "/images/kitchen.jpg"];
var imgHtml = "";
for (var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0){
        imgHtml += "<div class='col-wrap'>";
    }
    imgHtml += "<div class='item'><img class='imgitem' src='" + imgs[i] + "'></div>";
    if (i % 2 != 0 || i == imgs.length - 1){
        imgHtml += "</div>";
    }
}
document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = imgHtml;
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
.col-wrap{
    display:inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Note that you'll need to add a `<div id="wrapper"></div>` to your body for this script to replace the innerHTML of. The key thing here is the addition of the `.col-wrap` element around every two `.item` elements, allowing you to place them in columns of height 2.

(Edit) Oh right, here's an [example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lxmkK), if you wanted to know what this might look like. (It's a bit different with some extra styling, since I don't have access to your images, but the idea behind the script remains.)

I hope this was the behaviour you were looking for! If it wasn't, feel free to tell me and I'll be happy to help you further. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Make your items float right and then after the 4th item is written, add a div with `style="clear:both"` and write the next row.

Another alternative is to use a library like [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: Sorry, I wish I know how to. I know the HTML part but not the JS.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript to do that.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/pml2y1dl

```
.container {
  -webkit-columns: 50px;
  -moz-columns: 50px;
  columns: 50px;
}
```

The columns property is shorthand for column-width and column-count.  I favor using column-width alone as it works better with responsive design, but you could specify the exact number columns instead (`columns: 4`).

http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could only use CSS :

```
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; /* IE7 Hack */
    zoom: 1; /* FOR IE again... */
    max-width: 25%;
}
```

And make your container the width of 4 images.